nginx proxy manager similar solution for none docker environment
I am new into Reverse proxy and have basic understanding, i have did a afew research still don't get an answer what I am looking for i need some basic understanding weather the Scenario below can be achieve via reverse proxy or any other solution (yes i am aware i can change the management port listen on 80 or 443 this is not what i am looking for)
here is my scenario
I have couples' vm utility servers and NAS each management ports have custom ports (not 80.443). for example,
nas.abc.com:5000 where A record is 10.1.1.10:5000
web.abc.com:8080 Where A record is 10.1.1.11:8080
what i want to do is redirect or forward nas.abc.com:5000 to nas.abc.com no port 5000 involve. so, every time when i access the nas.abc.com don't need to provide port. preferer something like Nginx proxy manager that can handles ssl
Note, i have a Bit played around caddy ,haproxy, Nginx got so confused.
thank you for your help.

This question is similar to: How can I forward requests from my web server?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
